# page not loading using docker and symfony

Tags: docker, symfony

i am trying to run a page using docker and symfony using commands

```
docker compose up -d --build
docker compose exec php /bin/bash
symfony new .
symfony serve
```

I did it according to the example, in the example the page was loaded after the third command
Docker and symfony start but page doesn't render
[comands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv30h.png)

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ38N.png)

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.2'

services:
    database:
        container_name: database
        image: mysql:8.0
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: SmP
            MYSQL_DATABASE: sdb
            MYSQL_USER: symfony
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
        ports:
            - '4306:3306'
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    php:
        container_name: php
        build:
            context: ./php
        ports:
            - '9000:9000'
        volumes:
            - ./app:/var/www/symfony_docker
        depends_on:
            - database
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
        volumes:
            - ./app:/var/www/symfony_docker
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        depends_on:
            - php
            - database
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y zlib1g-dev g++ git libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony_docker
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash

RUN mv /root/.symfony5/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony

RUN git config --global user.email "mail@mail.com" \
    && git config --global user.name "qwerty" \
    && git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```

default.conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        index index.php;
        server_name localhost;
        root /var/www/symfony_docker/public;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log
        assess_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ ^index\\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass php:9000
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\\.php)(/.*)$;

            include fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

            fastcgi_buffer_size 128K;
            fastcgi_buffefs 4 256K;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256K;

            internal;
        }

        location ~ \\.php$ {
            return 404;
        }
}
```

I tried to do in different folders, but the result is the same
P.S. some data was changed on purpose, because it is my data

Comment: When there is webserver there should be it's logs as well, what you have done to investigate?? You have only posted what you have copied from the references but your question is missing the problem. So please look into the log one by one and share the error message if you don't know then ask here for help.